# Why does my CentOS machine think I still have Java 6 instead of 8 intalled?

Tags: centos, software-installation, java, version, uninstall

So I have Java 8 installed on my CentOS 6 machine;

```
rpm -qa
```

yields

```
jre1.8-1.8.0_161-fcs.x86_64
```

and

```
java -version
```

yields

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Yet my build file is failing, saying that;

> build.xml:223: This build requires Java version 1.8, not 1.6.0_21

From this code:

```
  <target name="check_versions"
    depends="check_java_version">
    <fail message="This build requires Java version ${java.version.required}, not ${java.version}."
      unless="java.version.ok"/>
  </target>
  <target name="check_java_version">
    <property name="java.version.required" value="1.8"/>
    <condition property="java.version.ok">
        <contains string="${java.version}"
                  substring="${java.version.required}"/>
    </condition>
  </target>
```

Anyhow, I did something naive. When I went to install Java 8 I of course had to uninstall my old version first. However I could not figure out how the old Java version was installed, or how to uninstall it. There were no installed Java 6 packages recognized by rpm, nor was there anything recognized by yum. As such as I couldn't use rpm or yum to uninstall it. It existed and /home/products, but inside I didn't find any sort of uninstall executable

So, I went brute force simply removed the entire directory (and used rpm to install 8). Now I'm guessing there is something akin to a window's registry still lingering around. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: you might `strace` the build process and see what files it is looking at

Comment: What is teh $JAVA_HOME set to?  What is your $PATH, and where is the (new) Java located?

Comment: @ivanivna, good call $JAVA_HOME was set to the old directory, now it is set to /usr/bin/java. But for some reason even after fixing that (and SS_JRE_HOME) I'm still having this problem.

Comment: @thrig I haven't used strace before and it outputs a lot for my build file, what exactly am I looking for?

Comment: `execve` calls involving `java` or other common java binary names or find the fail message and work backwards from that to see what was run. you may need a `-s 512` or something to show longer strings containing error messages

Comment: And `javac` yields?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an that there is still an Java 1.6 version installed on your system. Furthermore environment variables like `$JAVA_HOME` and `$JRE_HOME` might be still set to the old directory. There could also be symlinks like `/usr/java/latest` which are pointing to the former version.

I recommended to start with searching for the installation path of the old version and environment variables. To do so you may use commands like:

```
sudo find / -name "java"
grep --color -ir "JAVA_HOME\|JRE_HOME" /{etc,opt,var}/*
```